# Deducing the order of an ODE from its solution curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the smallest possible order of a linear, homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients which the following curves are solutions of?[image]

My thoughts: different frequencies for the oscillations imply minimum order $4$ because I need to solve two sets of $r^2+br+c=0$ characteristic equations. However I do not know what to do about the constant solution.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: The constant solution tells you that the ODE doesn't have a term like $cy$ with $c \neq 0$. It won't tell you much about the order, except that it is at least order $1$.